# Installing NumPy to a virtual environment on raspberry pi for python 3.7

Tags: python, numpy, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to install NumPy for python 3.7 on my raspberry pi as a part of installing OpenCV.
Originally when running

```bash
sudo pip3.7 install opencv-python mediapipe Flask==2.0.3
```

and then got error on building wheels for NumPy. I sequentially tried to use `--no-binary flag` but no luck either.

I then tried to install NumPy using apt package manager with `sudo apt install python3.7-numpy`, but this installed it into dist packages in `/lib/python3` rather then in `/lib/python3.7`. And somehow neither python3 nor python3.7 interactive shell cant locate and import it.

In any case I don't want to use os package manager, since I want to install it to a virtual environment.

Below is what seems to me like the relevant fragment from from the failed wheel build error message:

```
numpy/core/src/umath/loops_trigonometric.dispatch.c.src: In function ‘FLOAT_sin_NEON_VFPV4’:
      numpy/core/src/umath/loops_trigonometric.dispatch.c.src:202:20: internal compiler error: in convert_move, at expr.c:218
       NPY_NO_EXPORT void NPY_CPU_DISPATCH_CURFX(FLOAT_@func@)
```

To address one of the comments: I did create and activated a virtual environment. The issue is that to my knowledge there is no way to force apt to install python packages outside of global/user site-packagse or dist-packages.

Comment: related? [Python3.7 with Numpy on Raspbian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/99621/97626) on raspberrypi.stackexchange.com. Side-note: I cannot reproduce the error on a pi4 with Python 3.9. So if you have a chance of using a newer Python version, that could help.

Comment: @FObersteiner sadly not, I saw that and the issue mentioned there is that numpy errors out because of some c dependencies issues, In my case installation doesn't succeed.